# Embedding paginated report in Power BI Embedded Gen 2 - web application

Tags: powerbi, token, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a power bi paginated report which is published in the workspace, powered by a A2 SKU (power BI embedded gen2) so the paginated report workload is already enabled against the capacity and workspace.

Now I have 3 questions:

**question 1 :** to test this paginated report in our web application, what's the progress? I read MS documentation but couldn't figure it out. we already do have normal pbix REPORT configured in the web application and they are all showing up. however, for paginated report I guess I need to somehow add some controller to it? below please see the part we have for standard users:

```
<section id="report-container" class="section__content"
power-bi-access-token="@Model.Report.FirstOrDefault().AccessToken.Token"
power-bi-id="@Model.Report.FirstOrDefault().Report.Id"
power-bi-embed-url="@Model.Report.FirstOrDefault().Report.EmbedUrl"
power-bi-embed-pages="@Model.Report.FirstOrDefault().Pages">
</section>
```

**question 2:** if above solution (to view embedded paginated report in the web application) takes a long time to develop, then what other ways do I have to test if embedding paginated report works in our A2 capacity as an external users (I need to test it using access token)

**question 3:** based on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-paginated-reports?tabs=customers#step-6---embed-content-using-the-sample-application) in Microsoft documentation , do you have any sample code so that I use to generate mine?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**1:** This is the embedding configuration for Paginated Report, you can read about each of the properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embed-paginated-report).

```
let embedConfiguration = {
    accessToken: anAccessToken,
    embedUrl: anEmbedUrl,
    uniqueId: aReportId,
    tokenType: aTokenType,
    type: 'report'
};
```

**2:** For embedding a paginated report, an EM or P SKU is required.

**3:** You can explore the Playground to understand the various embedding features:

[Power BI Playground - Explore our APIs](https://playground.powerbi.com/explore-features)

There are some sample codes in this git directory you can use: [GitHub - microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples: A collection of Power BI samples for developer use](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/).

**References:**

[Embed a paginated report in Power BI embedded analytics | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embed-paginated-report)

[Embed paginated reports in your Power BI embedded analytics application - Power BI | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-paginated-reports?tabs=customers)

[Power BI Playground - Explore our APIs](https://playground.powerbi.com/explore-features)

[powerbi-docs/embed-paginated-reports-customers.md at live · MicrosoftDocs/powerbi-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerbi-docs/blob/live/powerbi-docs/developer/embedded/embed-paginated-reports-customers.md)